# Example of binary GCD for complex integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I know you can use bit shifting to speed up the [GCD algorithm for a pair of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm). Is there a way to apply this idea to gaussian integers?

Comment: Yes. It is possible, it's possible to a lot of kinds of integers (Eisenstein, etc). Read Stillwell's: Elements of Number Theory. But I'm not sure what you mean with *"this idea"*.

Comment: This idea being not using division, but bit shifting, comparison, and subtraction. I know the GCD algorithm exists for all Euclidean Domains. I did not realize you could use the binary gcd algorithm.

Comment: It looks like there's a '$(1+i)$-ary' algorithm due to André Weilert; see http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=749911 and http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F10722028_40#page-1 , and http://www.csie.nuk.edu.tw/~cychen/gcd/A%20Fast%20Euclidean%20Algorithm%20for%20Gaussian%20Integers.pdf for a brief mention of Weilert's algorithm and a related idea.